# Importacion de archivos excel por metodo POST, en C# Almacenar y mandar a una tabla en sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, excel, .net

Acudo a esta gran comunidad con la esperanza de dar solucion a mi problema, lo que pasa es que estoy intentando crear un programa, para importar archivos de excel, que se lean, y se importen a una base de datos, de la misma forma en como esta el Excel, para luego programar con estos datos, pero cuando trato de importar en la base de datos, me aparece que algunas columnas no aceptann valores nulos, pero es erroneo, ya que el excel contiene datos en dichas columnas, por lo que parece que no me lee los datos de excel, alguien podria ayudarme porfavor?,estoy muy embalado y lo necesito de urgencia.

Codigo de Controlador de excel

```
// ExcelController.cs

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

[Route("api/excel")]
[ApiController]
public class ExcelController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public ExcelController(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [HttpPost("upload")]
    public IActionResult UploadExcel(IFormFile file)
    {
        try
        {
            if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
            {
                return BadRequest("No se proporcionó ningún archivo o el archivo está vacío.");
            }

            var clientesData = ProcessExcelFile(file);

            SaveDataToDatabase(clientesData);

            return Ok(new { Message = "Datos importados y almacenados exitosamente." });
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, $"Error de formato al procesar el archivo Excel: {ex.Message}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, $"Error interno del servidor: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private List<Cliente> ProcessExcelFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        var clientesList = new List<Cliente>();

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.CopyTo(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;

            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
            {
                var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

                var headerRow = worksheet.Cells["A1:AH1"]
                    .Select(cell => cell.Text)
                    .ToList();

                for (int row = 2; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
                {
                    var cliente = new Cliente();

                    for (int col = 1; col <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; col++)
                    {
                        var property = typeof(Cliente).GetProperty(headerRow[col - 1]);

                        if (property != null)
                        {
                            var value = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Text;

                            if (property.Name == "vendor")
                            {
                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                                {
                                    value = "vacio";
                                }
                            }

                            try
                            {
                                property.SetValue(cliente, Convert.ChangeType(value, property.PropertyType));
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                // Manejar el error de conversión aquí
                                Console.WriteLine($"Error al convertir '{value}' a {property.PropertyType.Name}: {ex.Message}");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    clientesList.Add(cliente);
                }
            }
        }

        return clientesList;
    }

    private void SaveDataToDatabase(List<Cliente> clientesList)
    {

        clientesList.Take(5).ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Company);
            Console.WriteLine(x.Customer_ID);
        });

        try
        {
            _dbContext.Datos.AddRange(clientesList);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error al guardar en la base de datos: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error inesperado al guardar en la base de datos: {ex}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

`

Hice un models, con las columnas de la tabla, con una migracion cree la tabla en la base de datos, la cuestion es que todavia no reconoce los datos, sin embargo el archivo de excel contiene valores con parentesis, guiones, iguales entre otros, en el modelado esta establecido como String, no se si interfiera mucho en este caso, (Soy Practicante)

Al intentar importar el archivo en el back para que se envie a la tabla de sql server me sale est error en la consola

``````
    `Error al guardar en la base de datos: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
    fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
          An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'DbContext'.
          Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
           ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PriceableItem_description', table '"BASE DE DATOS".dbo.Datos'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
          The statement has been terminated. Error al guardar en la base de datos: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
    fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
          An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'DbContext'.
          Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
           ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PriceableItem_description', table '"BASE DE DATOS".dbo.Datos'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
          The statement has been terminated.Error al guardar en la base de datos: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
    fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
          An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'DbContext'.
          Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
           ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PriceableItem_description', table '"BASE DE DATOS".dbo.Datos'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
          The statement has been terminated.Error al guardar en la base de datos: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
    fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
          An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'DbContext'.
          Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
           ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PriceableItem_description', table '"BASE DE DATOS".dbo.Datos'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
          The statement has been terminated.`````



Modelado Cliente
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Cliente
{

    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }

    public string? Customer_ID { get; set; }

    public string? Customer_VAT_ID { get; set; }

    public string End_Customer_Company { get; set; }

    public string? DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public string Product_Name { get; set; }

    public string Vendor { get; set; } = "NO DATA";

    public string VendoReference { get; set; }

    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    public string PriceableItem_description { get; set; }
    public string? Material_Number { get; set; }

    public string? ContractID { get; set; }

    public string? ResellerContractID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Billing_Start_Date   { get; set; }

    public DateTime Actual_Charge_Interval { get; set; }

    public int Days_Billed { get; set; }

    public DateTime Billing_Interval { get; set; }

    public string BillableParameters  { get; set; }

    public decimal Costs { get; set; }

    public decimal Sales_Price { get; set; }

    public string Currency { get; set; }

    public string? Product_Code { get; set; }

    public int Costs_of_Unit  { get; set; }

    public int? Sales_Price_of_Unit { get; set; }

    public int UDRC_Value { get; set; }

    public int PriceableItemId { get; set; }

    public string ProductNumber { get; set; }

    public string PriceableItemType { get; set; }

    public string? Sales_Manager { get; set; }

    public string? SecondVendorReference { get; set; }

    public int CompanyAccountid { get; set; }

    public string? InvoiceReference { get; set; }

    public string? InvoiceLineNumber  { get; set; }

    public string? PurchaseOrderNumber  { get; set; }
}


Ejemplo de excel:

[![Excel 1][1]][1]
[![Excel 2][2]][2]
[![Excel 3][3]][3]




Si necesitan algun otro tipo de informacion haganmelo saber, porfavor estoy un poco embalado con este proyecto


LINK DE ARCHIVO MUESTRA EXCEL:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VcMwRhl0GsB9LOK5wtmjmIyBr8KMTC0C/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109677079306458935938&rtpof=true&sd=true



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HENtt.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCUf7.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9UZh.png





@Yuseff 

@Yussef Podrias ayudarme a identificar donde es y si lo hago bien?

// ExcelController.cs

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

[Route("api/excel")]
[ApiController]
public class ExcelController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public ExcelController(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [HttpPost("upload")]
    public IActionResult UploadExcel(IFormFile file)
    {
        try
        {
            if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
            {
                return BadRequest("No se proporcionó ningún archivo o el archivo está vacío.");
            }

            var clientesData = ProcessExcelFile(file);

            SaveDataToDatabase(clientesData);

            return Ok(new { Message = "Datos importados y almacenados exitosamente." });
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, $"Error de formato al procesar el archivo Excel: {ex.Message}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, $"Error interno del servidor: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private List<Cliente> ProcessExcelFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        var clientesList = new List<Cliente>();

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.CopyTo(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;

            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
            {
                var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

                var headerRow = worksheet.Cells["A1:AH1"]
                  .Select(cell => cell.Text.Trim().Replace(" ", "_"))
                    .ToList();

                for (int row = 2; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
                {
                    var cliente = new Cliente();

                    for (int col = 1; col <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; col++)
                    {
                        var property = typeof(Cliente).GetProperty(headerRow[col - 1]);

                        if (property != null)
                        {
                            var value = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Text;

                            if (property.Name == "vendor")
                            {
                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                                {
                                    value = "vacio";
                                }
                            }

                            try
                            {
                                property.SetValue(cliente, Convert.ChangeType(value, property.PropertyType));
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                // Manejar el error de conversión aquí
                                Console.WriteLine($"Error al convertir '{value}' a {property.PropertyType.Name}: {ex.Message}");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    clientesList.Add(cliente);
                }
            }
        }

        return clientesList;
    }

    private void SaveDataToDatabase(List<Cliente> clientesList)
    {

        clientesList.Take(5).ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Company);
            Console.WriteLine(x.Customer_ID);
        });

        try
        {
            _dbContext.Datos.AddRange(clientesList);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error al guardar en la base de datos: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error inesperado al guardar en la base de datos: {ex}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
 







LO hice de esta manera y me salio mas errores de que parece que se esta convirtiendo todos los datos de las columnas a string 




Error al convertir '01.10.2023 - 01.11.2023' a DateTime: String '01.10.2023 - 01.11.2023' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
Error al convertir '10,8' a Int32: Input string was not in a correct format.
Error al convertir '12,5' a Nullable`1: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]'.




y tambien en la consola me sale esto 

Error al guardar en la base de datos: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
      An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'DbContext'.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'VendoReference', table 'SiigoDb.dbo.Datos'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
``````

Comment: Ya planteaste iniciar con un archivo CSV?
Puedes pegar el código que estas usando o cual es tu problema técnico?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no tenemos codigo, no vemos el archivo de entrada, no vemos la tabla.. es muy dificil ayudarte a ciegas...

Comment: Lo otro es indicar la librería que estas usando para leer el excel, yo acabo de hacer una prueba y al parecer es otra

Comment: Igual, mirando esas imagenes, tu tienes que el header de `PriceableItem_description` tiene un espacio en lugar de un guion bajo

Comment: @Yussef Ya esta una muestra de excel, estoy usando el paquete de nuguet de EPPlus, entity framework de sql y tools, sql client, entre otro, En excel hay varios datos con espacio pero los puse con guion bajo, no se si interfiera, ya que el archivo de excel viene por defecto asi

Comment: Dos cosas, los campos de tu tabla son nulos? o no nulos? si pudieras mostrar tu DbContext seria bueno

Comment: @Castrof55 hablo de tu clase DbContext, agrega el codigo a tu pregunta

Comment: @dsr Es el modelo de Cliente, ese es mi dbcontext

Comment: Para probar que no se el asunto del guíón, reemplaza por`.Select(cell => cell.Text.Trim().Replace(" ", "_"))` en donde lees los headers y me avisas

Comment: @Yussef mira la actualizacion de la pregunta pls

Comment: El modelo tienes unos errores `Actual_Charge_Interval` debe ser string, `Costs_of_Unit` decimal y `Sales_Price_of_Unit` decimal (o decimal? ahí tienes que revisar tu). Con esos cambios a mi no me da errores, aun que a ti te avisa un problema en `PriceableItem_description` y a mi no. Estamos probando con el mismo excel?

Comment: `VendoReference` por `VendorReference`

Answer (score 0):

Revisé tu código y es lo que te decía en lo comentarios, tienes `PriceableItem_description` en tu modelo y en la cabecera tienes `PriceableItem description` con espacio en vez de guión bajos. Entonces nunca encuentra la propiedad cuando haces la reflexión y por ello queda nulo

Debes colocar:

```
 var headerRow = worksheet.Cells["A1:AH1"]
     .Select(cell => cell.Text.Trim().Replace(" ", "_"))
     .ToList();
```

De esta manera cambias los espacios por `_`

Luego, según el excel que has compartido tu modelo es incorrecto, debería ser:

```
public class Cliente
{

    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }

    public string? Customer_ID { get; set; }

    public string? Customer_VAT_ID { get; set; }

    public string End_Customer_Company { get; set; }

    public string? DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public string Product_Name { get; set; }

    public string Vendor { get; set; } = "NO DATA";

    public string VendorReference { get; set; }

    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    public string PriceableItem_description { get; set; }
    public string? Material_Number { get; set; }

    public string? ContractID { get; set; }

    public string? ResellerContractID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Billing_Start_Date { get; set; }

    public string Actual_Charge_Interval { get; set; }

    public int Days_Billed { get; set; }

    public DateTime Billing_Interval { get; set; }

    public string BillableParameters { get; set; }

    public decimal Costs { get; set; }

    public decimal Sales_Price { get; set; }

    public string Currency { get; set; }

    public string? Product_Code { get; set; }

    public decimal Costs_of_Unit { get; set; }

    public decimal Sales_Price_of_Unit { get; set; }

    public int UDRC_Value { get; set; }

    public int PriceableItemId { get; set; }

    public string ProductNumber { get; set; }

    public string PriceableItemType { get; set; }

    public string? Sales_Manager { get; set; }

    public string? SecondVendorReference { get; set; }

    public int CompanyAccountid { get; set; }

    public string? InvoiceReference { get; set; }

    public string? InvoiceLineNumber { get; set; }

    public string? PurchaseOrderNumber { get; set; }
}
```